# Explicit or closed form of matrix product series expansion $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} A^n B^n /n!$, which is close to matrix exponential $\exp{(A B)}$

Tags: definite-integrals, lie-algebras, matrix-calculus, matrix-exponential, formal-power-series

Is there an explicit or closed form of the following matrix product series

$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{A^n B^n}{n!} = ?$$

$A$ and $B$ are real valued square matrices that do not commute, i.e., $\left[A,B\right]\neq0$. $A$ is a diagonal matrix. $B$ is a symmetric matrix.

The power series representation $ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(A B)^n}{n!}$ of the *matrix exponential* $ \exp(A B) $ resembles to some extend the series above.

Note that there is an exact integral representation of the power series expression $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{A^n B^n}{n!}$ that is
\begin{align}
   A^{-1}\int_0^\infty dt e^{-t A^{-1}} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(2 \sqrt{t B})^{2n}}{4^n (n!)^2} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{A^n B^n}{n!}
\end{align}
Note that $ I_0 (x):=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{2n}/(4^n (n!)^2) $ is the *zeroth order Bessel function of the first kind*.

The underlying matrix ODE is
\begin{align}
 \dot{Y}(t) = A Y(t) B
\end{align}
with the solution $Y(t) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{A^n B^n t^n}{n!}$.

However, I am looking for an expression that is explicit without any integral representation or ODE solution.

Also, it would be enlightening to consider the special case where A is the identity matrix plus a small and diagonal (perturbation) Matrix $\sigma$, i.e. $A\approx 1+\sigma$.

Any suggestions to solve this issue are welcome.

Comment: For $\|B\| r< 1$,
$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{A^n B^n}{n!}=\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} \exp(A r^{-1} e^{-it})(1-B r e^{it})^{-1}dt$

Comment: The expression stems actually from another integral that I added in the initial post.

Comment: Just an observation: $X(t):=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{A^nB^n}{n!}t^n$ is a solution of the linear matrix ODE $X'(t)=AX(t)B$, but I don't know if this is any help.

Comment: The ODE representation is actually useful. Do you have also a proof for the ODE representation? However, I am still looking for an explicit function definition, that may arise out of matrix exponential identities.

Answer (score 3):

Given that the expression

$$Y(\lambda)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\lambda^n}{n!}A^nB^n$$ satisfies the differential equation

$$\frac{dY}{d\lambda}=AY(\lambda)B$$

We can use a [vectorization trick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)) to simplify this equation into the more familiar form

$$\frac{d}{d\lambda} \text{vec}(Y)=(B^T\otimes A)\text{vec}(Y)$$

that can be easily solved :

$$\text{vec}(Y)=e^{\lambda (B^T\otimes A)}\text{vec}(I_{n})$$

where $I_n$ is the $n\times n $ identity matrix. Despite my best efforts, de-vectorizing this formula in a meaningful way has been difficult, and I believe that it isn't really desirable anyway, since Kronecker products offer natural solutions to matrix equations of the form $AX+XA^H=Q$ which admit a similar expansion as the one presented. Also, finding a numerical solution from the formula presented is straightforward to implement, although it is more expensive computationally to work out, since the dimensions of $B^T\otimes A$ is $n^2\times n^2$.

Answer (score 0):

> Any suggestions to solve this issue are welcome.

I don't really have any good ideas, but ***if*** it so happened that *A* and *B* anticommuted, like the Pauli matrices $\sigma_3$ and $\sigma_1$,
then you may note the alternating signs in
$$
(AB)^2= -A^2 B^2,\\
(AB)^3= -A^3 B^3,\\
(AB)^4= A^4 B^4,  \\
(AB)^5= A^5 B^5,\\
(AB)^6= -A^6 B^6,\\
(AB)^7= -A^7 B^7,...
$$
recursively.

You then have
$$
Y=I +ABt-\frac{(AB)^2t^2}{2!} -\frac{(AB)^3t^3}{3!} +\frac{(AB)^4t^4}{4!}
+\frac{(AB)^5t^5}{5!}- \frac{(AB)^6t^6}{6!}- \frac{(AB)^7t^7}{7!} +...\\
=\cos (ABt) + \sin (ABt),
$$
which you may refashion into exponentials, if you must...

It manifestly solves your differential equation.

---

***Addendum to revised question on diagonal perturbation***

For a diagonal perturbation, the perturbation series is straightforward,
$$
A^n= I + n\sigma +\frac{n(n-1)}{2!}\sigma^2+... ~~~~\leadsto \\
Y= \sum_{n=0}^\infty (I + n\sigma +\frac{n(n-1)}{2!}\sigma^2+...)B^nt^n/n! \\
= \left (I +\sigma Bt+ \frac{\sigma^2 B^2t^2}{2!} +...\right ) 
e^Bt.
$$
You may observe, however, that to sum the entire perturbation series in *σ*, you need, of course, to know the answer for *A*, since it has an identical commutator with *B*. Shifting *A* by the identity cannot change the structure of the problem.

Comment: Interesting. Unfortunately in the problem above the matrices are not anticommutative, i.e. $\left\{A,B\right\}\neq0$.

Comment: A tractable generic expression is unlikely without some type of systematic connection to powers of *AB*...